# Adding page navigation to a Javascript back and forward slider

Tags: javascript, navigation, element

So I have this slider that has back and forward functions and I am aiming to add buttons for each slide individually.

I have tried using a similar `document.querySelectorALL('.dots')` to pull all the `.dots` but I am failing assigning them to slides. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Code for pulling the arrow buttons loaded on each slide:
`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.next')).forEach((ctrl) => ctrl.addEventListener('click', (ev) => this.navigate(ev, 'next')));`

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.prev')).forEach((ctrl) => ctrl.addEventListener('click', (ev) => this.navigate(ev, 'prev')));`

Navigate function:

```
navigate(ev, direction) {
            if ( this.isAnimating ) {
                return false;
            }
            this.isAnimating = true;
            const currentGrid = this.grids[this.current];

            this.current = direction === 'next' ? (this.current < this.gridsTotal-1 ? this.current+1 : 0) : (this.current > 0 ? this.current-1 : this.gridsTotal-1);
            const nextGrid = this.grids[this.current];
            const filled = this.CONFIG.filledColor;
            currentGrid.hide(!!filled).then(() => {
                nextGrid.show(!!filled).then(() => this.isAnimating = false);
                if ( this.CONFIG.hasTilt ) {
                    this.onmousemove(ev);
                }
            });
        }
```

HTML Snippet for the dots navigation

````
<ul class="slidernav test">
  <li class="pulse" id="section-1"><use xlink:href="#circle"></use></li>
  <li class="pulse" id="section-2"><use xlink:href="#circle"></use></li>
  <li class="pulse" id="section-3"><use xlink:href="#circle"></use></li>
</ul>```
````

Comment: add a snippet of your code html css and javascript

Comment: i have used this slider found on [codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2017/07/19/css-grid-layout-slideshow/)

Comment: updated the code with the html dots navigation as well

Comment: if you are using a third part library, check into documentation the dots may can be a option to set on slider initialization

Comment: unfortunately it`s no third party library used with built in functions. I have used the tutorial to integrate the slider on my website, however i would like to add extra dots buttons where each is assigned to a slider

Comment: introduce a counter for the slides, increase and drecrease it according to prev or next  click. then add a function "jump to" for pass the index of clicked dot. within jumpTo function you can subtract the clicked dot index from counter in this way you can know how many time you have to trig the click on next or prev button to show the right slide